# update procedure error syntax near '='

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, updates

I simple want to update the price with for example here 3, but this with a stored procedure.

I already tried it with normal syntax:

```
update tblPrijs 
set PrijsVerkoop = PrijsVerkoop + 1
where PrijsId = '6';
```

and this works fine.

But my stored procedure always returns :

```
updatetblPrijssetPrijsVerkoop=PrijsVerkoop+3.00wherePrijsId=11
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

and I don't know what I did wrong..

The stored procedure:

```
alter PROCEDURE updatePrice 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@table nvarchar(50),
@field nvarchar(50),
@increase nvarchar(50),
@id nvarchar(50),
@value nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @sql as nvarchar(400);
-- Insert statements for procedure here
set @sql = 'update' + @table + 'set' + @field + '=' + @field + '+' + @increase +
'where' + @id + '=' + @value

print @sql /* drukt het resultaat van concat af */
exec(@sql)
END
GO
```

This is what I write in my query:

```
updatePrice'tblPrijs', 'PrijsVerkoop','3.00', 'PrijsId','11'
```

sorry for the dutch names of fields and tables...

I think it is something small and obvious that is wrong but I just can't see it..

This is in SQL Server 2012

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add some spaces in there.

This:

```
set @sql = 'update' + @table + 'set' +@field + '=' ...
```

if you add the following parameters:

- @table = SomeTable
- @field = SomeField

will result in this sql:

```
updateSomeTablesetSomeField=
```

Surely that's not what you intended.

I'm assuming by the `print @sql` statement that you wanted to print your sql statement before executing it. What did it show?

Here's something to try:

```
set @sql = 'update ' + @table + ' set ' + @field + ' = ' + @field + ' + ' + @increase + ' where ' + @id + ' = ' + @value
```

I added spaces inside each string, at the start and at the end. Some of those spaces are not strictly needed, but they won't change the outcome either.

Comment: it showed this: updatetblPrijssetPrijsVerkoop=PrijsVerkoop+3.00wherePrijsId=11 so i simple have to add some space?... like ' '?

Comment: I added a new statement at the bottom, please try that.